# How to perform both save and print functions by button click?

Tags: javascript, php

```
<input type="submit" class="button" name="submit" value="Save & Print">
```

The code below will run for saving in PHP:

```
<?php
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "......");
    if(mysqli_connect_error())
    {
         die("There was an error connecting to database.");
    }
    else
    {
        if(isset($_POST['submit']))
        {
            $query = "INSERT INTO `tbl` (`regno`) VALUE ('$_POST[regno]')";
            mysqli_query($link,$query);
        }
    }

?>
```

For printing I send a *divname* to `printDiv()` function:

```
    function printDiv(divName) 
    {
    var printContents = document.getElementById(divName).innerHTML;
    var originalContents = document.body.innerHTML;
    document.body.innerHTML = printContents;
    window.print();
    document.body.innerHTML = originalContents;
    }
```

I need both operations should trigger on button click. How can I do this?

Comment: you can use Ajax to solve this.

Comment: ajax will create a XMLHTTP request and send the data to backend via javascript and after saving it you can get response back from server with which you can proceed to print

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to stack overflow,

Use Onclick event to achieve this.

```
<input type="submit" class="button" name="submit" value="Save & Print" onclick='printDiv('idName')'>
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you can use the [meadroid](http://www.meadroid.com/), it's a cross-browser library that you can use it to print your desired HTML section.

Second, You should run print instruction at first, and after that, you should submit your form by JavaScript.

```
function PrintAndSubmit()
{
     //some code to print (like Meadroid commands) 
    document.MyForm.submit();
}
```

and call this function in the clicking event of your submit button:

```
<input type="submit" class="button" name="submit" value="Save & Print" onclick="PrintAndSubmit()">
```